# How to get chrome logged in user's email id through website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, privacy-policy

I visited [wishfin.com](http://wishfin.com) and one minute later I received their promotional email. I know this could be by chance but I am curious to know that if it is possible to get chrome logged in user's email id through website e.g. `javascript`?
Sorry, if this question is not relevant but I **Googled** it too, I have got no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the chrome profile information is controlled through the chrome.identity API - specifically getProfileUserInfo. [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo)

It returns the email & a UUID for the signed in profile.

**However** you must give the website permission for them to get this data, specifically the identity.email permission.

Unless you gave them the permission, the website did not receive your email from google chrome.

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. This is for getting identification via Chrome extension. The website cannot get such information and requires user to install a specific plugin.